Move the object smoothly without using cframe or position in the direction of the mouse
Basically what i want to do is when i hold q for example, the object that im holding should push in the direction my mouse is beforeafter holding q
Now i know how to do something when holding a key, but im not familiar with how to push it without using cframe or position. I tried to use cframe or position but it just flies away without limits, and the object is on a rope which is not what i need. Any help is appreciated!

Use a system like this:
--Server Script
directon=Vector3.new(0,0,1)
part=script.parent
moving=true
while moving do
    part.Position=part.Position+direction

This script checks if moving is true, then moves at a rate of 10 studs/sec along the Z axis. You can add extra logic to change the direction and the moving bool. If u want to get the mouse position in the world, use a script like this:
--Local Script
local mousepos=game.Players.LocalPlayer.Mouse.Hit

You could then use some logic to determine the part's current position and then move it accordingly to the mouse position.
Hope this helps!
